# Calculate expected color temperature of daylight

Tags: colors, location, light

I have a location (latitude/longitude) and a timestamp (year/month/day/hour/minute).

Assuming clear skies, is there an algorithm to loosely estimate the color temperature of sunlight at that time and place?

If I know what the weather was at that time, is there a suggested way to modify the color temperature for the amount of cloud cover at that time?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that in the world of photography, **color temperature** is only [one axis](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/108962/43103) (blue/yellow axis) of the white balance, the other being the **tint** (green/magenta axis).

Comment: Very related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66448/how-do-you-estimate-colour-temperature-based-on-the-position-of-the-sun-in-the-s

Answer (score 3):

I suggest taking a look at [this paper](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/papers/sunsky/) which has nice practical implementation for CG applications:

> **A Practical Analytic Model for Daylight A. J. Preetham Peter Shirley Brian Smits**
>
> **Abstract**
>
> Sunlight and skylight are rarely rendered correctly in computer
>   graphics. A major reason for this is high computational expense.
>   Another is that precise atmospheric data is rarely available. We
>   present an inexpensive analytic model that approximates full spectrum
>   daylight for various atmospheric conditions. These conditions are
>   parameterized using terms that users can either measure or estimate.
>   We also present an inexpensive analytic model that approximates the
>   effects of atmosphere (aerial perspective). These models are fielded
>   in a number of conditions and intermediate results verified against
>   standard literature from atmospheric science. Our goal is to achieve
>   as much accuracy as possible without sacrificing usability.
>
> Both [compressed postscript](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/papers/sunsky/sunsky.ps.gz) and [pdf](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/papers/sunsky/sunsky.pdf) files of the paper are available.
>
> Example [code](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~shirley/papers/sunsky/code) is available.
>
> Color images from the paper are shown below.

Link only answers are discouraged but I can not post neither sufficient portion of the article nor any complete C++ code snippet here as both are way too big. Following the link you can find both right now.

Comment: here's a updated link to the paper: https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps124/spring08/assign/07_papers/p91-preetham.pdf